# unity run function from coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

hi why dosn't this work 
i'm trying to rotate a game object from a cororotine the function runs but not the rotate if i put the rotate in the update it runs fine im confused thanks for any help

```
       using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class waitthendosomthing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool beingHandled = true; //  bool
    void Update()
    {
        //transform.Rotate(6, 0, 0);// this runs 
        if (beingHandled == true )
        {
            StartCoroutine(HandleIt());// run function
        }

    }

    void rotateit()
    {
        transform.Rotate(6, 0, 0);// this dosnt run
        print("running this function");
    }

    IEnumerator HandleIt()
    {
            beingHandled = false;
            print("BeingHandled is off");
            rotateit();
            //transform.Rotate(6, 0, 0); // or this
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.1f);
            //transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0); // or this
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.1f);
            beingHandled = true;
            print("BeingHandled is on");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works in update is because update is called on **every** frame. So every frame the cube will rotate by 6 degrees and continuously rotate as expected

The co-routine executes rotate only twice, once to 6 degrees and after 3.1 seconds back to 0 degrees.

If you want to rotate in the co routine you will have to implement it differently:

for example:

```
        double time = 0.0f;

        while (time < 3.1f)
        {
            time += Time.deltaTime;
            rotateit();
            yield return null;
        }
```

This will rotate the cube continuously for 3.1 seconds and then stop.

Comment: in general you should consider to use e.g. `transform.Rotate(6 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);` in order to not rotate fixed 6 degrees / frame but rather 6 degrees / second.